# How to change expiring and expired emails to send to admin via WP filter hook in Paid Memberships Pro plugin..?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

[Paid Memberships Pro](http://paidmembershipspro.com) has a bunch of default email templates, that are triggered by different events to send to either a user/member or the admin, depending on the event (some events have two templates: one to the user, one to admin).

The plugin offers a slew of [hooks and filters](http://www.paidmembershipspro.com/hooks-filters/) for customization convenience.

Here is the [filters provided in the PMPro email class and its entire source on GitHub](https://github.com/strangerstudios/paid-memberships-pro/blob/v1.7.8.1/classes/class.pmproemail.php#L92), and [implementation here in the crons](https://github.com/strangerstudios/paid-memberships-pro/blob/v1.7.8.1/scheduled/crons.php#L39).

How might I be able to only change the email recipient for a particular template? And/or BCC the admin only for a particular template?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

By the way I am trying to achieve this in a separate plugin, you know, not edit the plugin itself, so I can keep it updated and such...

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this by using the hooks.

The first one that occurs to me is that you can use the pmpro_email_filter filter to modify the PMProEmail instance.

For example, the following piece of code would change the recipient email to "new_email@example.com" if the email template is "something":

```
add_filter('pmpro_email_filter', 'modify_email_recipient');
function modify_email_recipient($pm_pro_email) {

    if ( $pm_pro_email->template == 'something' ) {
        $pm_pro_email->email = 'new_email@example.com';
    }

    return $pm_pro_email;
}
```